# How to use String properties in fastest-validator

Tags: node.js, validation, npm

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastest-validator

I'm using `fastest-validation` in my NodeJS application. I've been having great success with it. Unfortunately, I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

If you take a look under `String` (located here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastest-validator#user-content-string)

I'm attempting to utilize the property `numeric` as I have a string that is a number that I would like to validate. I'm not able to find any examples, so I was left with the assumption I must set the property to `true`. This doesn't appear to work as I've tried to validate this theory by also setting another field that is a numeric string and set the property of `alpha` to true. I fully expected my 'label' to pass and my 'value' field to fail. But both passed.

How are you supposed to used these properties?

See below for my code:

```
buildSchema.catalogPages = {
 type: "array", items: {
  type: "object", props: {
   label: { type: "string", empty: false, numeric: true },
   value: { type: "string", empty: false, alpha: true }
  }
 }
}

const v = new Validator()
const check = v.compile(buildSchema)
check(valuesToCheck)
```

Here is my data:

```
const valuesToCheck = [
 {
  label: "9"
  value: "9"
 },
 {
  label: "12"
  value: "12"
 },
```

**EDIT**

I just figured out my issue. I have a handler function that checks my schemas and valuesToCheck. What I was doing was returning the `check(valuesToCheck)` with the assumption it simply returns true or false. But in fact, if the check fails, it returns an array of what failed (which is awesome). I'm going to accept tam.teixeira's answer as it helped me realized I need to update my handler to check if it's a Boolean true or an array (aka it failed).

Comment: `const check = v.compile(buildSchema)` here why not put instead `compile(buildSchema.catalogPages)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote it this way to compress my code to only present the issue. i don't actually have it setup this way. Was primarily focused on figuring out the properties of the String as I want to include the 'numeric' property.

Comment: But the thing is that it works for me in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should not be something related to the schema itself, in the following example:

```js
const Validator = require('fastest-validator');

const schema = {
  myItems: {
    type: 'array',
    items: {
      type: 'object',
      props: {
        label: { type: 'string', empty: false, numeric: true },
        value: { type: 'string', empty: false, alpha: true },
      },
    },
  },
};

const valuesToCheck = {
  myItems: [
    {
      label: '9',
      value: '9',
    },
    {
      label: '12',
      value: '12',
    },
  ],
};

const v = new Validator();
const check = v.compile(schema);
console.log(JSON.stringify(check(valuesToCheck), null, 4));
```

Indeed it fails validation with errors:
`$> node fastestValidatorTest.js`

```js
[
    {
        "type": "stringAlpha",
        "message": "The 'myItems[0].value' field must be an alphabetic string.",
        "field": "myItems[0].value",
        "actual": "9"
    },
    {
        "type": "stringAlpha",
        "message": "The 'myItems[1].value' field must be an alphabetic string.",
        "field": "myItems[1].value",
        "actual": "12"
    }
]
```

So i got your expected behaviour: "'label' to pass and my 'value' field to fail"

So my conclusion is that maybe something is not right in the `buildSchema.catalogPages` part, to me it feels a bit suspiscious and i also got the expected behaviour with your example, but i've changed the schema object to be simpler.

PS: Thanks for the question i didn't knew the library, so learned something new, which is cool

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you so much, I'll take a look at this and get back to you!